# How to redirect R to local repository?

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I have rstudio connected with rconnect (both are rstudio products or tools) on Linux OS. When i try to publish shiny application documents (app.R) from rstudio, process or log says:

**Installing required R packages with 'packrat::restore()'....**
**Curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'cran.rstudio.com'**

I don't want R to go outside (like cran.rstudio.com) to find any R packages since i have R packages already installed.

Question: What is the setup or configuration i can perform to tell rstudio or rconnect to go to specific directory to find packages if require?

Comment: try `packrat::set_opts(local.repos = c("~/projects/R"))`

Comment: is there any way to set up centrally for all users? so that whenever any user try publish any shiny app/document from rstudio and if any packages require, R can look for local repository first (for example - we have all packages downloaded at "/r/packages")? and if you can please tell what "c" stands for after "=" sign? Thank you. Appreciate your comment

Comment: i don't know if you can do it like this, if you load a package shiny never download it, it just load from your library, you have to manualy install all packages you are using on the shiny server

Comment: I did update .Rprofile.site fiel with                                                          local({ r <- getOption("repos")
<- "http://server.company.com:1234/src/contrib" options(repos=r)
}). when I try to publish shiny app document, i get,                                    Deploying bundle: 70 for application: 31 ...
Installed packrat SHA is: ffhdfg
Packrat is up-to-date. R version: 3.2.2. packrat version: 0.4.8.11
Audited package hashes with local packrat installation.
# Installing required R packages with `packrat::restore()` 
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'cran.rstudio.com'